# Changing some elements in cdcalendar.cls

Tags: calendar

I'm using a template from LianTze Lim [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/customisable-calendar-with-events/htkctjjgmxjx). Where in cdcalendar.cls so that \event only the mark, name, and date are printed. For example,

**[mark] Masa Pengenalan Lingkungan Sekolah: 3-5**

[image]